# Email to rss on server

Tags: email, rss, feed

for my group at the university I'd like to set up a server-sided email-to-rss service.
It should work like that, that different people can send emails to a certain address (nothing proprietary like gmail but a certain imap or pop server) which will the be translated into an rss feed. One main and important feature has to be that one can see the sender of the email in the feed. Furthermore it would be nice (to take the load off the server) if the emails get translated to a feed only once a day or so.

Does anyone has some input on this subject? Are there any scripts/services which will allow that?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "reinventing the wheel", you could use a mailing list that supports RSS. Your people can then write the mails to the mailing list and you can then use the mailing list's RSS feed however you intend to.

This should help you find a solution: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=mailing%20list%20rss

Comment: Thanks. That was a good tip. I just found out that our universities mailing list server also offers rss feeds. Question resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Pick a programming language you're familiar with, then use either an imap library to fetch the E-mails (through cron, every hour or something like that), or if you have access to procmail on your mail server, launch your script as an email arrives (this shouldn't be too much work to handle for a server, unless you're talking a vast amount of E-mail).

The script would just insert the E-mails into a database, before extracting them and outputting the RSS-feed directly from that (this shouldn't be more than a handful of lines of code).

There's a couple of providers that does this for you, although it seems that the most popular ones have disappeared. [Advanced Email2RSS](http://www.advancedemail2rss.com/) seems to be an option, although I have no idea how good they are or if it'll even solve your issue.

Comment: I was asking because I didn't want to program it myself and because I think that surely this has been done by somebody else. And since this stuff should be too public I also would decide against an external provider.